# Xcode seems to have duplicate 'entries' for all classes in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode9

I don't know when this happened, or what I have done to make it so, but every time I CMD-click a class name with the intention of navigating to the correct class file, it asks me which of the following two classes I want to enter, and gives me a list of two of the same class..

[image: Duplicate class]

In the image I have created two completely new classes with unique names. There exists no other class named "MyNewClass" in my project or anywhere on my entire machine. When I attempt to "enter" that class, by CMD-click, it presents these two options. They both lead to the same place. This has never been a problem before, and was working completely fine a few weeks ago. I don't remember when this started to happen, but I think it's only been during Xcode 9.2.

I feel like this has something to do with some search path or something, but I'm not completely sure how/where/why etc.
It's a big app, containing a few CocoaPods. It has 8 different targets, but they all share the same classes.

(**And yes, I have tried cleaning and wiping derived data**)

Comment: Just a wild guess, but can it be that you somehow "include" something twice? I had similar issues in Obj-C if you incorrectly include headers (which leads to double inclusion).

Comment: @iur A great guess! I searched my entire project for "import Google*" and a wild import appeared. It fixed the warning-issues with GoogleMaps, so thanks for that. However, the initial problem still persists. I still get two sets of the same classes whenever I cmd-click. It only happens with this project (if I create a new project, or open an older project, it doesn't happen there). I thought the Google-warning was related, but apparently it wasn't.. I will update the question and remove the Google-part of it. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the main question - did you try to restart Xcode? It sounds stupid but just an hour ago I had a Swift compile error of a class not confirming to protocol, which actually was conforming. Only Xcode restart helped.

Comment: Another question is if you have maybe modified your build settings in Xcode for derived data location?